# AS3 Creating algorithm for 6 ^ 20 results

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, data-structures, tree

I have searched a lot for something to point me in the right direction,
but I can't seem to figure it out/find something that is right for my situation.

In my game you play for a total of 20 years.
Each year you can choose from 6 cases. Each case changes different values,
and each year is influenced by the values of the previous year.
Due to some random factors there is almost always a different end result/optimum result.

In case of the optimum result. I used to calculate the highest case each year individual.
But since each year is influenced by the values of the previous year, it is far from certain 
that those 20 year cases are the optimum result. For example:

[image]

**Edit: In this example I've drawn the situation with 3 cases instead of 6.**

This will be the case for 6 scenarios in a period of 20 years.
So there will be 365.615.844.0062.976 different end results. And I want to get the highest
end result.

Could anyone please give me some advice/ideas on how to approach this ridiciously large 
data structure. 
I hope I gave a clear explanation on this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If generation of inherited numbers is random you should iterate all tree for highest result. In you case it takes near 1.5 year =(

Comment: How do you come up with 1,5 year?

Comment: Calculate via induction.

Comment: 6^20 * 0.0001 (say each iteration takes 0.1 ms to calculate) = 11600 years. Not really viable ;)

Comment: What you have here is a classic case of the curse of high dimensionality. Unless you have some way of forecasting what the values will be, obtaining an optimal value is probably practical impossible. You really need to settle for an approximate solution or a more predictable way to be able to calculate the optimum. If you decide to do one of those I'll post an answer that might help.

Comment: @Jonatan Hedborg, 10^8 iterations ~ 1 second. Differ on you CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will certainly try to look into
a simpler approach for getting (in that case) almost the optimum.

Comment: @Толя Naturally it will differ from CPU to CPU, but I doubt you'll get a 100 million full branch evaluations per second in AS3 (you  get maybe 200 million empty (class) function calls per second on an average computer, and I'd wager there's a lot more than that in the evaluation).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate? The end scores for *all* variations? That's indeed a lot of data. Or are you just searching for the single variation with the highest end score?

Comment: Can you calculate the values when populating the tree?

Comment: How are the values calculated from year-to-year?  There might be a clever way to determine which path has the optimal solution without actually brute-forcing them all.  If there's not, you're going to have to settle for an approximation..

Comment: @delnan I'm searching for the single variation with the highest end score. But due to randoms, and the effect of the previous result.
You can't really now it forehand. Every game the result can differ.

Comment: @AzzyElvul I am actually calculating the values while populating the tree.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Something like: Value = oldValue * random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you won't be able to find a guaranteed best solution for this problem. A good middle ground might be to go, for example, 5 years deep (7776 variations) and select the 5 best scoring solutions of those. Then repeat the process from each of those partial solutions. That should yield about 124416 calculations, which shouldn't take too long to test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain of a good way to approach the problem itself; however, you may want to look at the solutions for Project Euler's problems 18 and 67. It is a pathfinding problem similar to this one, and it could provide you some insight.

As for data storage, have you considered using a B-Tree? The file I/O might be a bit costly, but it sounds as though you don't have to do any intensive real-time calculations in the game.

Comment: I thank you for the interesting Project Euler site/problems.
However I think that the problems 18 and 67 are not the same as mine.
Those problems work with triangles in which each path is possible.
But (see image above for reference) in my case each end result has
a unique path.

Answer (score -1):

The sollution is very similar to the min max algorithm, which is standard game/ai programming 101. Take a look at the wikipedia page of min max to get a nice start in the right direction
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

Comment: I have read the whole principle of the minmax algorithm. I understand it's use. And how I can implement this.
However I'm stuck on the fact that there can be a maximum of
365.615.844.0062.976 end results. And I have to keep each of those value's stored somewhere. Thats a lot of values and too much for an array.